# Organising UISplitView with iPhone device rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to fix some odd behaviour which occurs when I rotate an iPhone app using `UISplitView` from portrait to landscape.

I have two Master Table Views. When I am in portrait I can navigate from Master Table View 1 to 2 fine, but when I rotate to landscape from Master Table View 2, it then appears in the detail pane whereas I would like it to stay on the 'Master side'. Images below. Happy to add code as requested!

**Portrat, navigated to Master Table View 2**

[image]

**When rotated:**

[image]

**Desired outcome:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use SplitViewController then to achieve this requirement use proper size classes and variations as shown in the attached image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEtYf.png